# No SCRIPT_URI or SCRIPT_URL in my phpinfo

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I am running WAMP 2.2 with Apache 2.0.50 and PHP 5.2.11 and I looked in my phpinfo and I cant find `SCRIPT_URI or SCRIPT_URL` I tried adding this script to my httpd.conf file for apache and it didn't work. Anyone got any ideas to `SCRIPT_URI or SCRIPT_URL` to my phpinfo? I need it for a site I am running on my local machine.

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
<IfModule headers_module>

####### INITIAL SETUP #########################
    RewriteEngine on

####### SET HEADERS #########################
    #get and set the host name
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_HTTP_HOST:%{HTTP_HOST},NE]
        RequestHeader set x-orig-host "%{INFO_HTTP_HOST}e"


    #get and set the host port
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_SERVER_PORT:%{SERVER_PORT},NE]
        RequestHeader set x-orig-port "%{INFO_SERVER_PORT}e"


    #If the uri starts with a slash and some alphanumerics, then make a 
    #group of that until the first non-alpha (ie. the next slash)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[\w-]+)
    #Save the content of the regex match group ( %1 ) in an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT:%1,NE]
    #Set a header with the content of the environment variable
        RequestHeader set x-orig-context "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT}e"


    #If the accept-header contains a number after ;version= then make a regex group of that number
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \+json;version=(\d+)$ 
    #Save the content of the regex match group ( %1 ) in an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_ACCEPT_VERSION:%1,NE]
    #Set a header with the content of the environment variable
        RequestHeader set x-orig-accept-version "%{INFO_ACCEPT_VERSION}e"


    #If the accept-header contains kasia2. followed by some letters, 
    #then make a regex group of those letters
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} kasia2.(\w+).*
    #Save the content of the regex match group ( %1 ) in an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_ACCEPT_NAME:%1,NE]
    #Set a header with the content of the environment variable
        RequestHeader set x-orig-accept-name "%{INFO_ACCEPT_NAME}e"


    #If https is on ...
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    #...then set the protocol environment variable to "https"
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_PROTOCOL:https,NE]
    #If https is off ...
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #...then we assume it must be "http"
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_PROTOCOL:http,NE]
    #Finally, set the protocol header
        RequestHeader set x-orig-protocol "%{INFO_PROTOCOL}e"


    #Get the request uri and set an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
    #Build the whole original url out of the available parts. SCRIPT_URI is always null, otherwise we could have used that.
        RequestHeader set x-orig-url "%{INFO_PROTOCOL}e://%{INFO_HTTP_HOST}e%{INFO_REQUEST_URI}e"
    #In addition make an url with only the host and context, for convenience
        RequestHeader set x-orig-url-base "%{INFO_PROTOCOL}e://%{INFO_HTTP_HOST}e%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT}e"

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Is there something I have to do in my php.ini file to get this to work?

Comment: ___Apache 2.0.50___ Wow

Answer (score 1):

**Solution first:** I believe this is a `.htaccess` vs. virtual host difference. If you use `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` you get `REDIRECT_URL` set, whereas if you use them in a virtual host in the main apache configuration you instead get `SCRIPT_URL` set. My fix is very pragmatic:

```
if(array_key_exists('SCRIPT_URL',$_SERVER)){
  $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'];
  }
elseif(array_key_exists('REDIRECT_URL',$_SERVER)){
  $url = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
  }
else throw...;
```

**Background explanation:**

I've just been comparing two servers side-by-side, one (Mint 16, i.e. Ubuntu 13.10) where `REDIRECT_URL` is available (and `SCRIPT_URL` is *not*), and another (Ubuntu 14.04) where none of the `REDIRECT_*` variables are set but `SCRIPT_URL` is available with the same information.

They are Apache 2.4.6 vs. 2.4.7, and PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6 vs. 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3. I've just compared the `phpinfo()` output side-by-side, and apart from minor version changes in libraries they are basically identical, *except* for the REDIRECT vs. SCRIPT `$SERVER` variable difference!  (To be thorough: the Mint 16 machine has mcrypt installed where Ubuntu 14 does not, while Ubuntu 14 has readline installed where the Mint 16 machine does not.)

The biggest difference is the server where `SCRIPT_URL` is set has the RedirectMatch in a virtual host, and needed an explicit forward slash before the script name:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /main.php [NC,L]
```

Whereas all the other servers I have where `REDIRECT_URL` instead  is set have the rules in a .htaccess file, and do not need that forward slash:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ main.php [NC,L]
```

(I don't explicitly set RewriteBase in either case, but [the manual entry](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) seems to suggest why I don't need it, and that is also suggesting to me that the mechanism might be different enough that different environmental variables get set.)

Comment: `SCRIPT_URL` and `SCRIPT_URL` are documented in the Apache docs as [environment variables maintained by mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#EnvVar) - so from that they _should_ be present in the $_SERVER superglobal. However, for some reason, they are not always set. I have 3 servers; they are only set on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Added this line along with the script above and now it works `RewriteEngine On`